# Spliting Text Nicely over Multiple Lines (i.e. for titles)

Tags: php

I'm fighting over a way to have text wrap nicely to fit into set div boxes. Browsers wrap the text if it's too long to fit on one line which is expected, but this can often lead to rather nasty looking presentation.

For example, this looks fine:

```
This is the title
```

But if I have a longer title, it may end up wrapped like this:

```
This is a slightly longer
title
```

As you can see the second one doesn't really look very nice, what I'm aiming for is something like this:

```
This is a nicer
wrapped title
```

I know how big the containing DIV will be, so that's not a problematic variable, but I'm trying to wrap my mind around all the possible ways of achieving nicely formatted titles and their flaws. So the question is, what would be the best way of doing this? I can think of a few ways, but they start to get exponentially more complicated if it wraps over more than 2 lines.

EDIT:
I'm currently using this - https://xnode.org/paste/19 - to try and even out the split lines, although I'm sure it's far from perfect.

Comment: This will be problematic to do using PHP. Sure, when the font used inside the div is monospaced, it is as trivial as getting the correct amount of characters per line. But if it is not, you will end up with a much more complicated algorithm that has to include fonts styles and more. And you will have to make sure that it renders in the browser exactly as you think it will.

Comment: I've put together something quickly that works a little like Wordwrap, but gives me more control - https://xnode.org/paste/18 - it still relies on me guessing how many characters will fit, but technically everything should scale with browsers and if I keep the wrap value a little lower than what should really fit, it should avoid issues. Any better ideas are welcome though.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the newlines and then use [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function

Comment: Doesn't help even out the distribution over multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the wordwrap function http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Comment: Doesn't help even out the distribution over multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `wordwrap` function and give this CSS for the `DIV`:

```
div {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect over broken lines, it only justifies text, it wont even out how much text is split over each line.

Comment: What I said is, use both the `word-wrap` as well as `justify`. I am still confused, what you wanna achieve.

Comment: Wordwrap wont take into account how long the sentence is in total thus it'll wrap at X value, same as the browser already is on its own. The key is that IF the text has to wrap, I want the lines to be split evenly, see the examples I posted in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If http://fittextjs.com/ doesn't do the trick, try something along these lines...

Count the characters in your title and decide if it is going to need 1 line, 2 lines 3 lines, etc. (there will be some trial & error involved)

Replace all the spaces apart from where you want line breaks with `&nbsp;` (non-breaking spaces) and let the browser do the word wrapping.

In other words, in your `This is a nicer wrapped title` example, there are 29 letters, so you need a break around half way or just after, so replace the first non-breaking space after position 14 or 15 with a regular space ie between 'nicer' and 'wrapped', and that should do the job. Same thing in thirds or quarters for longer lines.

Sorry no code but from the examples you gave above you should be ok coming up with your own implementation.

Comment: The nbsp idea is a good one, prevents the browser wrapping as well as my own wraps (that way I can use one or the other). Not a fan of doing it via the browser though due to unexpected behavior, i.e. that fittextjs site didn't actually render the title in the right size till I refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this jQuery plugin that does what you want

```
$.fn.prettyBreak = function () {

    return this.each(function () {

        var element = $(this);

        var elementLineHeight = element.css("line-height").replace("px", "");

        var elementContent = element.contents();

        element.wrapInner("<span style='white-space: nowrap'>");

        element.find("br").remove();

        var textWidth = element.find("span").width();

        element.html(elementContent);

        var elementText = $.trim(element.text());

        if (element.is(":visible") && textWidth > element.width() && element.height() < elementLineHeight * 2.1) {

            var middle = Math.floor(elementText.length / 2);
            var before = elementText.lastIndexOf(" ", middle);
            var after = elementText.indexOf(" ", middle + 1);

            if (middle - before < after - middle) {
                middle = before;
            } else {
                middle = after;
            }

            var s1 = elementText.substr(0, middle);
            var s2 = elementText.substr(middle + 1);

            element.html(s1 + "<br> " + s2); // note the space after the tag

        } else {
            element.html(elementText);
        }

        if (element.is(":visible")) {
            element.css("opacity", 1);
        }

    });
}
```

Usage:

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
    $(".pretty-break:visible").prettyBreak();

    setInterval(function () {
        $(".pretty-break:visible").prettyBreak();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Github link: https://github.com/SumoSoft/PrettyBreak